# Node readableStream that uses pipe needs a _read() method?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe

The following code is what I got from a tutorial page on Node Stream as a working example:

```
const Stream = require('stream')

const readableStream = new Stream.Readable()
const writableStream = new Stream.Writable()

writableStream._write = (chunk, encoding, next) => {
    console.log(chunk.toString())
    next()
}

readableStream.pipe(writableStream)

readableStream.push('ping!')
readableStream.push('pong!')

writableStream.end()
```

However, when I tried it, I got the error of

`NodeError: The _read() method is not implemented`

which I don't quite understand, as I think a readableStream that writes to `pipe` does not need a `_read()` method. No?

**UPDATE:**

> *it is the mandatory `_read` method of a readable stream that pushes data out*

Hmm... check out https://github.com/samerbuna/efficient-node/blob/main/400-node-streams.adoc#implement-a-readable-stream. I.e., the following code work, a readableStream that `push`es to `pipe`, and it does not need a `_read()` method.

```
const { Readable } = require("stream");

const inStream = new Readable();

inStream.push("ABCDEFGHIJKLM");
inStream.push("NOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

inStream.push(null); // No more data

inStream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: This example is wrong, because it is the mandatory `_read` method of a readable stream that `push`es data out, not the application. You can at least make it work if you set `readableStream = new Stream.Transform()` instead.

Comment: I've updated my OP, and know the fix now -- need to push before pipe.

Comment: But if you can do pushing before piping, you don't need piping at all. In such a case, you can `write` directly to the writable stream instead. A readable stream should be `pipe`d _before_ it starts emitting data.

Comment: _" readable stream should be piped before it starts emitting data"_, I do agree on that, for the rest, I'll do more reading...

Comment: Honestly the Streams API of Deno is superb as it attempts to implement the Web Streams API standard. Even beyond the browsers do, like `ReadableStream` type being an async iterator by default and such. You can do like `for await (const line of Deno.open("./myFile.zip").pipethrough(new DecompressionStream("gzip")).pipethrough(new TextDecoderStream())){handleLineString(line)}` kind of things.